# What is the best way to dynamically specify the redirect url for OAuth strategies in passport.js?

Tags: oauth, passport.js

I have setup my facebook auth per passportjs docs:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) { ... });
  }
));

app.get('/login/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'))
   .get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login'}));
```

All this works fine. However, there are cases (such as token expiration) when I want to automatically redirect the user to the page that the user was on before initiating the login request. So I tried to plumb a query string param through the login request (from client to server to facebook and back). But I cant see a way to specify that in the callbackURL.

Furthermore, when I tried hard-coding some context param to the config callbackURL (eg: "http://www.example.com/facebook/callback?redir=lastUserPage") I get an OAuth parse error. Interestingly enough, Facebook does respond correctly with the access code as well as the redir param, but it fails with OAUTH exception:

```
FacebookTokenError: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request
   at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:198:12)
   at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:345:16)
   at C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:171:43
   at C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:177:18
   at passBackControl (C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:124:9)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Sources\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:943:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Note that I had this working using WIF before. I don't see any security concerns with passing additional query string parameters through the OAuth process..

Any idea how I can get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do what you're asking, but for your desired end goal you could:

1. Save a cookie before authenticating
2. Authenticate the user
3. on the resulting callback page, check for the cookie and redirect if present.

Wouldn't this work just as easily?

Comment: In my scenario, saving the state in a cookie was problematic for a variety of reasons. In any case, I found out that this can be done using the state parameter of the strategy.